# Microsoft Surface for reading textbooks and writing math by hand?

Tags: soft-question, math-software

As a PhD student I am increasingly wanting to get a tablet and the new Microsoft Surface tablets appeal to me greatly as I am a big fan of the UI. I wonder if anybody has got hold of it yet and what their opinions are on it with regards to reading mathematical textbooks and PDF files, and secondarily, taking notes via some sort of pen? Is the screen good enough for this purpose? Is scrolling in PDF files smooth?

I'd of course like to do more than just maths on it but discussing other aspects of the Surface is probably off-topic.

Thanks.

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing, and have been considering buying if its stylus input is worthwhile. It's worth noting that Microsoft *does* have a math handwriting recognition application that converts handwriting into, sadly, MathML.

Comment: So do I, to compare usability against my Samsung Android Galaxy Note 10.1, which mostly does what I want, but has at least several usability flaws. I wouldn't be surprised if MSFT is doing one of those beta testing programs.